# Backbone.js and JQuery Mobile Router

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, routes, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm developing an application with Backbone.js and JQM, but I have problems with methods not being fired.
This is my code:

```
class HomeView extends Backbone.View
  constructor: ->
    super

    @el = app.activePage()

    console.log(@el)

    @template = _.template('''
      <div>

      <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c" data-filter="true">
        <% venues.each(function(venue){ %>
          <li><a href="#home"><%= venue.getAbstract() %></a></li>
        <% }); %>
      </ul>

      </div>
    ''')

    @render()

  render: =>
    @el.find('.ui-content').html(@template({venues : Venues}))    
    app.reapplyStyles(@el)

class HomeController extends Backbone.Controller
  routes :
    "#venues-:cid" : "show"
    "#home"  : "home"

  constructor: ->
    super
    @_views = {}

  home : ->
    console.log("home")
    @_views['home'] ||= new HomeView

  show: (cid) ->
    console.log("show")
    @_views["venues-#{cid}"] ||= new ShowVenueView { model : Venues.getByCid(cid) }
```

Setting the route to #home, it is not get called.
However if I set it to just home, and disable both ajax and hashListening like this

```
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
```

Brings me to a 404 page not found.
What's the problem with this?

Comment: From what I've read, there are some differences in the way JQM and Backbone work with hash tags.  Have you tried this:  https://github.com/azicchetti/jquerymobile-router

Comment: I suffered a lot of pain before realizing what a horrible choice jQuery mobile is for developing mobile-optimized web applications. BackboneJS can handle everything jQuery mobile can, with a lighter framework, and much less obtrusive code. Here's a good starting place: http://trigger.io/cross-platform-application-development-blog/2012/03/02/how-to-build-fast-html5-mobile-apps-using-backbone-js-zepto-js-and-trigger-io/

Answer (score 0):

I have used the pattern described here:
http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/03/using-backbone-js-with-jquery-mobile/.

Very short, very efficient, and most important - it works.

Comment: you should post some of the content in the link. If the link evers fails, then this will not be helpful to other users.